# How do you stop a game after a collision takes place?

Tags: actionscript, hittest

I am creating a very simple 2d game where you slide the player across the stage to avoid "rocks" that fall from the top. What I want to happen is for the game to end when my player comes into contact with one of my rocks. This is the code I have right now, I have tried everything so I don't have a clue if I am close to getting it or am way off.

```
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Collision);

function Collision( e:Event ):void{

       if(player.hitTestObject(rock1))
       { 
            gotoAndStop(3);
       }
}
```

when I use this code the player just passes right through the rocks and the frame doesn't change. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: where, how do you define the rock?

Comment: the rocks are defined as rock1,rock2,rock3,rock4,.....widerock. That is both their symbol and instance names. The player is a smaller square at the bottom of the screen that moves only in either x direction. The players instance name and symbol is "player"

Comment: So you are only testing for `rock1` all other rocks that hit the player are not tested. Share more of your code, to get a clearer picture of what you are doing.

Comment: `stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);
function loop(e:Event)
{       rock1.y +=10;
 rock2.y +=10;
 rock3.y +=10;
 rock4.y +=10;
 rock5.y +=10;                                                   Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT; 
this.stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin);
function onTouchBegin(e:TouchEvent):void{
 player.x = e.stageX;
}                stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Collision);

function Collision( e:Event ):void{

    if(player.hitTestObject(rock1))
    { 
      gotoAndStop(2);
    } 
} 
}`

Comment: and yes, as of right now I am only testing for rock 1. I figure when I get this one to work I can copy the code for the others.

Comment: It is better to put the rocks in an array and "walk" the array to change their values. Is there a `stop()` action in the frame you jump to? And which frame do you want to go to? your code mentions 2 and 3?

Comment: Copy code for others?  You really need to understand some fundamental things about programming. Start at the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the logic to move the falling rock and to control the player. First you have to put a trace statement to make sure the collision happens, then to end the game just remove the event listener and do whatever is needed like showing a game over screen:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Collision);

function Collision( e:Event ):void{

   if(player.hitTestObject(rock1))
   { 
       trace("player collided with rock1!");

       // stop the enter frame event from firing
       stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Collision);

       // go to game over screen or what ever
       gotoAndStop(3);
   }
}
```

Also is better to call the enter frame handler function something better than Collision like onEF, loop...etc

Comment: The first part of that works perfectly. The only thing that isn't working is when the player collides  with the rock it is not changing screens.

Comment: did you make sure when the player collides with the rock the "player collided with rock1!" is traced?

Comment: other than that, make sure you are calling the gotoAndStopStop() in the right place. Also generally, it is not the best idea to use frames to change scenes in games. You should create MovieClips in library and load them when needed.